# Why MKCircle is not displayed on MKMapView iOS8

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview, mapkit

I create new overlays like this:

```
MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:region.coordinate radius:region.radius];
[self.mapView addOverlay:circle];
```

also I implemented delegate method:

```
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay {
    MKCircleRenderer *circleRenderer = [[MKCircleRenderer alloc] init];
    circleRenderer.fillColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    circleRenderer.alpha = 1.f;
    return circleRenderer;
}
```

both parts of code are called, mapView != nil at that moment, it's delegate set,
but I cannot see the circle on my map.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than `init`, call the `MKCircleRenderer` method `initWithCircle`.

Obviously, make sure the `delegate` of the map view is set, that your code that adds the overlay and that instantiates the renderer is called at all, etc., but `initWithCircle` is the likely culprit.

Answer (score 7):

As per @Rob suggestion you need to `init` `MKCircleRenderer` using other method `initWithCircle`.

```
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay {
    MKCircleRenderer *circleRenderer = [[MKCircleRenderer alloc] initWithCircle:overlay];
    circleRenderer.fillColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    circleRenderer.alpha = 1.f;
    return circleRenderer;
}
```

Also make sure that fence distance is proper enough to visible the circle in map.

For example:

```
CLLocationDistance fenceDistance = 100000;
MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:region.coordinate radius:fenceDistance];
[self.mapView addOverlay:circle];
```